# Is the address of a string literal guaranteed not to be null?

Tags: c++, string-literals

Is it guaranteed that `"stuff" != nullptr` and `"" != nullptr`?

An online search did not give useful results.

Edit: I am asking if it is guaranteed that the address of any string literal is not null, which neither of the duplicate questions explicitly answers.

Comment: It must be.  A string literal is an array, and an array cannot be at address NULL; no object has that address.

Comment: Vaguely related is that `"" == ""` may be either true or false.

Comment: A string literal must have at least one element (the null terminator) so must be stored in an array and can't be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the address of a string literal guaranteed not to be null?

Yes.

A null pointer cannot be derefernced. A string literal can be converted to a pointer, which can be dereferenced to get the first character of the string. Ergo, a string literal can't be a null pointer. Q.E.